# How create task with fixed work which change duration so that enough work is spent on the task

Tags: ms-project

How do I create a task in Microsoft Project Pro 2019 that takes 1 person 8h to complete. I don't care about the duration or anything else, only that there are 8h spent working on the task.
Normal working hours in the project are 8h/day.

- If I add a resource working 100% in the project, the duration should be set to 8h
- If I add a resource working 50% in the project,then the duration should be set to 16h.
- Optional: If possible, I want to limit the task to max 1 person at a time (i.e. the task is about nailing and we only have one hammer).

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the task with type = Fixed Work.  (You can set the task type on the Task Form-in the lower pane, on the advanced tab of the Task Information dialog that opens when you double-click the task, or by inserting the "type" column into the task table and making the entry there.)
2. Set Work = 8h
3. Assign your resource at whatever percentage you want (Using the Task Form or the TI dialog).  The task duration will adjust automatically.

Comment: Setting the task to be Fixed Work is not a problem, but the only TimeSpan field that's available in the Task Form or the Task Information dialog is Duration.